# How to exploit a file upload to an IIS 5.1

Tags: exploit, asp.net, iis, ftp, microsoft

I found the following services in a testing environment:

```
21/tcp   open  ftp           Microsoft ftpd
80/tcp   open  http          Microsoft IIS httpd 5.1
```

The FTP server allows anonymous logins and the content can be displayed website.

How can this be exploited to gain further access to the server?

I assume I need to verify if ASP or something similar is running and then upload an exploit, which I then access via the website, correct?

**edit:**

I scanned multiple hosts in a testing environment and amongst others this one target hosts an FTP service, which allows anonymous logins.

With the anonymous login I can upload files to a directory, which can then be accessed with the Browser, by directing it to the targets IP address (e.g. `http://192.168.0.58/uploads/myfile`).

I'm unsure how to exploit this, to gain access to the server. My first thought was to create a reverse TCP shell in form of an ASP file.

What could I do to exploit this scenario?

**edit2**

I've tried to upload the reverse TCP shell to the target and accessed it with my browser, having a listener on my side ready.

That resulted in an unprivileged shell on the server, which is a nice first step.

Now the question for me is, are there other approaches to exploit this? Other than serving malicious files via the FTP server.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone could answer this question with the few details you list here.